# Python - Function definition occupy memory?

Tags: python

I know that function call has to occupy memory, but what about function definition? Is it memoryless?

Answer (score 0):

Information must be stored somewhere. Since functions are part of a script being executed that has been loaded into memory, and might be needed at any time, I assume it is in the memory it is stored. Furthermore, in C, you can put pointers (variables linking to memory addresses) pointing to memory that is containing a function. This means that the function occupies memory when using C, so probably does so when using python as well.